# Share extension view with swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, share-extension

I have an existing Swiftui app that has two screens: a listview to show all items and a form screen to process the text in certain types of images and save them into a DB.

I'm trying now to add a share extension feature where users can select the image from any other app and feed it to mine. I have tried to follow some tutorials on the net, but none has worked, either outdated or missing some key details.

Is it even possible, or should I simply go back to UIkit to achieve this feature?

Thanks

Comment: What are the issues with the samples in the documentation?

Comment: @loremipsum is there really one that is using SwiftUI for building a share extension view? If so, could you kindly share the link?

Comment: If you are talking about the actual extension you start with UIKit and can create SwiftUI views to customize Apple has a ton of videos on how to make them work together.